# How can I make my SQL query for StackExchange shorter?

Tags: sql, join, data.stackexchange.com

I was trying to track my performance here in **SO** using [StackExchange - Query Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and came up with this query:

At first I have this one to get the list of my answered questions:

```
Select Distinct a.Id, a.CreationDate, u.DisplayName, p.Title, p.Tags, 
   CONCAT('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/', p.Id, '#answer-', a.Id) as Link
From Posts a 
   Inner Join Posts p On a.ParentId = p.Id 
   Inner Join Users u On a.OwnerUserId = u.Id
   Inner Join PostTags pt on p.Id = Pt.PostId
   Inner Join Tags t on pt.TagId = t.Id
Where a.OwnerUserId in (
  9461114   --Me
  )
  And a.PostTypeId = 2  -- Answer
  And p.PostTypeId = 1  -- Question
  And t.TagName in ('jquery')
```

Then I did another query to get all the answers raw score (Upvote, Downvote, Accepted)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT v.PostID as Id, vt.Name, COUNT(*) AS CNT
     FROM 
     Posts p
       INNER JOIN Votes v
         ON v.PostId = p.Id
       INNER JOIN VoteTypes vt
         ON v.VoteTypeId = vt.Id
     WHERE
     p.OwnerUserId in
     (
      9461114   --Me
      ) 
  GROUP BY 
  vt.Name, v.PostID) s_tab pivot (min(CNT)for [Name] in ([UpMod], [DownMod],[AcceptedByOriginator]))AS PVT
```

Then to make things easier, I used `LEFT JOIN` to merge the two queries that I have, and here's what I came up with:

```
Select a.Id, a.CreationDate, a.DisplayName, a.Title, a.Tags, a.Link, b.UpMod as Upvote, b.DownMod as DownVote, b.AcceptedByOriginator as Accepted
From 
(Select Distinct a.Id, a.CreationDate, u.DisplayName, p.Title, p.Tags, 
   CONCAT('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/', p.Id, '#answer-', a.Id) as Link
From Posts a 
   Inner Join Posts p On a.ParentId = p.Id 
   Inner Join Users u On a.OwnerUserId = u.Id
   Inner Join PostTags pt on p.Id = Pt.PostId
   Inner Join Tags t on pt.TagId = t.Id
Where a.OwnerUserId in (
  9461114   --Me
  )
  And a.PostTypeId = 2  -- Answer
  And p.PostTypeId = 1  -- Question
  And t.TagName in ('jquery')
  ) a 
Left Join 
  (SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT v.PostID as Id, vt.Name, COUNT(*) AS CNT
     FROM 
     Posts p
       INNER JOIN Votes v
         ON v.PostId = p.Id
       INNER JOIN VoteTypes vt
         ON v.VoteTypeId = vt.Id
     WHERE
     p.OwnerUserId in
     (
      9461114   --Me
      ) 
  GROUP BY 
  vt.Name, v.PostID) s_tab pivot (min(CNT)for [Name] in ([UpMod], [DownMod],[AcceptedByOriginator]))AS PVT
  ) b on a.Id = b.Id
```

This is too long and I feel like there are some other ways to do this without making the query look like this.

I have tried and tested my query and am quite sure that it works just how I wanted it to. I just want it to be shorter. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following query is the combination of your two inner queries (without pivoting).

```
    SELECT
      a.Id,
      a.CreationDate,
      u.DisplayName,
      p.Title,
      p.Tags,
      CONCAT('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/', p.Id, '#answer-', a.Id) AS Link,
      vt.Name AS VoteType,
      COUNT(v.Id) AS VoteCount
    FROM 
      Users u 
      INNER JOIN Posts a ON u.Id = a.OwnerUserId AND a.PostTypeId = 2  -- Answer
      INNER JOIN Posts p ON a.ParentId = p.Id  AND p.PostTypeId = 1  -- Question
      INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.Id = pt.PostId
      INNER JOIN Tags t ON pt.TagId = t.Id AND t.TagName in ('jquery')
      LEFT JOIN Votes v ON a.Id = v.PostId 
      LEFT JOIN VoteTypes vt ON v.VoteTypeId = vt.Id
    WHERE u.Id = 9461114   --Me
    GROUP BY
      a.Id,
      a.CreationDate,
      u.DisplayName,
      p.Title,
      p.Tags,
      p.Id,
      vt.Name
```

Everything is built around the user table and the appropriate filters were moved from the `WHERE` section directly to the `JOIN`. The votes were attached directly to the answers with a `LEFT JOIN`. The final, pivoted query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.CreationDate,
    u.DisplayName,
    p.Title,
    p.Tags,
    CONCAT('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/', p.Id, '#answer-', a.Id) AS Link,
    vt.Name AS VoteType,
    COUNT(v.Id) AS VoteCount
  FROM 
    Users u 
    INNER JOIN Posts a ON u.Id = a.OwnerUserId AND a.PostTypeId = 2  -- Answer
    INNER JOIN Posts p ON a.ParentId = p.Id  AND p.PostTypeId = 1  -- Question
    INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.Id = pt.PostId
    INNER JOIN Tags t ON pt.TagId = t.Id AND t.TagName in ('jquery')
    LEFT JOIN Votes v ON a.Id = v.PostId 
    LEFT JOIN VoteTypes vt ON v.VoteTypeId = vt.Id
  WHERE u.Id = 9461114   --Me
  GROUP BY
    a.Id,
    a.CreationDate,
    u.DisplayName,
    p.Title,
    p.Tags,
    p.Id,
    vt.Name
) s_tab pivot (min(VoteCount) for [VoteType] in ([UpMod], [DownMod], [AcceptedByOriginator])) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to see your answers on jquery questions.

In your query you are joining tags, thus having to account for multiple rows per answer, although the posts have a redundant tags string. You are doing this in order to limit your results to jquery questions, but by joining and possibly multiplying rows, you need `DISTINCT` later to get rid of what you produced. This is not considered good style. What you want is to look up tags. We look up things in the `WHERE` clause with `EXISTS` or `IN`.

As to getting and counting votes the most elegant way should be an `OUTER APPLY` - or even a `CROSS APPLY` as we are talking about aggregates - on your answers.

```
select
  a.id, a.creationdate,
  u.displayname,
  q.title, q.tags,
  v.up, v.down, v.accepted,
  concat('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/', q.id, '#answer-', a.id) as link
from posts a
join posts q on a.parentid = q.id
join users u on a.owneruserid = u.id
cross apply
(
  select
    sum(case when vt.name = 'UpMod' then 1 else 0 end) as up,
    sum(case when vt.name = 'DownMod' then 1 else 0 end) as down,
    sum(case when vt.name = 'AcceptedByOriginator' then 1 else 0 end) as accepted
  from votes v
  inner join votetypes vt on v.votetypeid = vt.id
  where v.postid = a.id
) v
where a.owneruserid = 9461114
and a.posttypeid = 2  -- answer
and q.posttypeid = 1  -- question
and exists
(
  select *
  from posttags pt
  join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
  where pt.postid = q.id
  and t.tagname in ('jquery')
);
```

This is not the shortest query we can write for the task, but it's probably the most performant way to approach it. I also consider this query very readable and thus maintainable, because you can easily see for instance why we check PostTags and Tags.